# AHK, how to update the value of GUI Hotkeys via list

Tags: autohotkey

```
Gui, Add, Text, x20 y13 Left, spam left click hotkey
Gui, Add, Hotkey, x140 y10 vHKspamleft
Gui, Add, Text, x20 y53 Left,hold left click hotkey
Gui, Add, Hotkey, x140 y50 vHKholdleft
Gui, Submit, NoHide

hotkeyList := ["HKspamleft", "HKholdleft"]
for key, val in hotkeyList
    GuiControl,, % %val%, x
```

I have two GUI Hotkeys. I want to be able to set the displayed value of these Hotkeys to "x" via a list of controlIDs. The above code will not update values, however hardcoding `GuiControl,, HKspamleft, x` will work. How can I get this done via a list of controlIDs?

Answer (score 0):

You're exiting the legacy syntax by telling AHK to evaluate an expression in this parameter:
`% %val%`, but then you are still using the legacy way of referring to a variable `%%`.
In the modern expression syntax you refer to a variable by just typing its name:

```
hotkeyList := ["HKspamleft", "HKholdleft"]
for key, val in hotkeyList
    GuiControl,, % val, x
```